# creating a method to find the 2nd occurrence of a value in an int array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

For a homework exercise i was asked to create a method to find the 2nd occurrence of a value in a int array.  I am able to find the first and the last occurrence but for some unknown reason i cant not find the 2nd.  im wanting to return the index value but i cant add it to the end because it says it does not exist, which i understand because its outside the loop. im just really frustrated please help

```
public int SearchSecOccur(int[] arr, int sValue)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
    {
        if (arr[index] == sValue)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 3)
            {
                return arr[index];
            }
        }  
    }   

    return index??;
}
```

Comment: Just define `index` **outside** your loop and assign it **within**.

Comment: Also you're currently returning your third match, but more importantly you're returning the value you're matching with, Isn't the index what you want returned?

Comment: i never thought about that thanks heaps that works, ive been stuck on this for a few days now thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public int SearchSecOccur(int[] arr, int sValue)
    {
      int count = 0;
      int ret_index = -1;

      for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
        {
          if (arr[index] == sValue)
        {
          ret_index = index;
          count++;
          if (count == 2)
            {
              return ret_index;
            }
        }

        }
      return -1;
    }
```

If second occurrence found then it will return its index,
else return -1 i.e. there is no second occurrence of it. 
in your code, count == 3 will will return third occurrence, not the second  one, because you are intitalizing count with 0.

Comment: just a question why have u initialize ret_index with -1?

Comment: because i am not sure that there will be 2nd occurrence of sValue. So if i wont find it, it will return -1, means I can check the same in return value by calling function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the second occurence, why you stop at the thrird?

```
if (count == 3)
{
   return arr[index];
}
```

You also return the value not the index, so try this:

```
if (count == 2)
{
   return index;
}
```

At the end of the method you might want to return `-1` because there was no second.

For what it's worth, an extension that works with any type(generics) and enables to specify the number of occurence which index you want:

```
public static int IndexOfNthOccurence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T sValue, int numOccurence)
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    foreach (T item in seq)
    {
        if (comparer.Compare(sValue, item) == 0) count++;
        if (count == numOccurence) return index;
        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: ive done that and it doesnt work because i need a return value at the bottom so what would i be returning?

Comment: @AtaahuaMoaketonuatu: i have told it in the answer, it starts with : _"At the end of the method you might ..."_ Note that i've provided an extension method that is seful for other cases.

Comment: thank you and sorry i didnt see u comment until after i had commented